Modify module feature by subclassing
I would like design a python module so that its features can be modified by means of subclassing. This pattern is for instance used by the unittest module where you make a subclass of unittest.TestCase and define your tests as methods on this class. When unittest.main() is executed are these methods somehow run.
How do you design a module to allow modification by subclassing in this way?
I made the following module which allows modification of its behavior by subclassing the class MyRangeA. This implementation uses the magic methods __new__ and __sublasses__. It works as far as I can tell but I would like to know if there is a better way or if there are some issues with this way.
class MyRangeA:

    def __new__(cls, upper_limit):

        if cls.__subclasses__():

            assert len(cls.__subclasses__()) == 1,\
                f"Expected not more than one subclass of {cls} but the following exist:\n{cls.__subclasses__()}"

            subclass = cls.__subclasses__().pop()

            return super().__new__(subclass)

        else:

            return super().__new__(cls)


    def __init__(self, upper_limit):

        self._upper_limit = upper_limit

    def __iter__(self):

        return iter(range(self._upper_limit))

def print_my_range():
    print(str.join(", ", [str(num) for num in MyRangeA(3)]))

The client code could look like this:
from dunder_new import MyRangeA, print_my_range

class MyRangeB(MyRangeA):

    def __iter__(self):

        return iter(range(1, self._upper_limit + 1))

print_my_range()

The client code modifies print_my_range so that "1, 2, 3" is printed instead of "0, 1, 2".

It's unclear why you need the __new__ method, except to restrict the number of subclasses and possibly disallow subclassing more than one class. You can achieve the same behaviour without __new__. MyRangeA --> init & iter and MyRangeB(MyRangeA) --> only iter would give the same results as your current code.

new is used to decide which class is instantiated by the call  MyRangeA(num). The backend code uses only this class. Without changing which class is instantiated in new the function print_my_range would not change its behavior. Hope that makes it clear why I am using new

No to "new is used to decide which class is instantiated by the call MyRangeA(num)." because print_my_range will always use MyRangeA. If the client has to modify the print_my_range method itself by mocking/monkey-patching, then that's not happening via subclassing. If the client code has to modify print_my_range and subclass MyRangeA, then it's unnecessary since just one of those is enough. print_my_range should have the signature: def print_my_range(my_range_class): print(str.join(", ", [str(num) for num in my_range_class(3)])) and called with that class.

In my example the client code does not have to modify print_my_range. It's behavior is changed ONLY by subclassing MyRangeA. I agree that for this specific example it would be better to pass a range class to print_my_range. However, it is just an easy example to illustrate the problem at hand. The problem is how to design a module so that its behavior ´can be changed by subclassing a class, like you do using the unittest module.

That's a cool trick but then you completely lose the original behaviour of MyRangeA and if you or the client creates MyRangeC(MyRange): ..., then print_my_range() triggers the AssertionError: Expected not more than one subclass of ... error. If that's exactly what you want - only one subclass then okay - along with all the restrictions/new problems it creates.

@aneroid: the idea is to design the module so that the behavior of MyRangeA can be globally changed by only subclassing it, i.e. this is the desired result. The question is how this can be achieved in the  best way.  Is there a better way of doing that than using the magic function new. Is there any problem using new.
